# How does the downloads count for an app in the Google Play Store calculated

Tags: android, google-play

I'm trying to get official answer of how install count in Google's play app page is calculated. 
I'm referring to the counter showing the rough indication of "1M+","50,000 - 100,000" and so on..

To be more accurate - my question is:
If my app distributed by the Galaxy app store / Orange app store - will Google play know eventually to count also this installations although they installed via Samsung's galaxy store?
(Assuming I have my app published also in Google Play with the same package and signature..)

My assumption would be that only download's initiated from the play store would count in Google's play page, but I couldn't find any official source confirming that.

Comment: how is google play supposed to know what is going on in 3rd party app stores?

Comment: @TimCastelijns: It tracks what packages are installed on the device

Comment: @TalKanel Why would it do that?  Why would they care about it if it wasn't installed via the app store?  They'd be more likely to dock you users so you look less popular than add to your total.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/play/u2P3BiUmqPU:

> Play Store will count only the apps installed apps from itself. If you have installed an app from third party without changing anything in the app manually then this will not be counted but you will get updates on Play Store, once you update the app installed from third party then it will be counted. If you have installed an app that was cracked then it won't be added, also you will not get any updates. It will not be counted anymore.

That's only a semi official source. However if you go to the google play console and navigate to *User Acquisition > Acquisition Reports* you will see the following

[image]

There is a listing for 3rd party referrers but as the name implies and the tooltip ("Unique users who installed your app from a deep link to Google Play from a third-party referrer.") confirms, this only counts referrals to the play store listing itself.

If google play's install count included 3rd party app store installs, surely those would be mentioned as an acquisition channel on this page.